# How to test a python file that contains no functions and has multiple input calls?

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-unittest

I have the following python file `two_strings.py`:

```
str1 = input()
str2 = input()
combined = str1 + "," + str2
print(combined)
```

I then have a jupyter notebook file called `test_two_strings.ipynb`:

```
import sys
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import two_strings
from io import StringIO

sys.path.append('Challenge10/')

class SimpleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_defs(self):    
        defs = [v for v in dir(two_strings) if v[0] != '_']
        assert 'str1' in defs, f'Definition for str1 not found'
        assert 'str2' in defs, f'Definition for str2 not found'
        assert 'combined' in defs, f'Definition for combined not found'
    
    def test_inputs_outputs(self):
        user_input = [
            ['a','b'],
            ['10','sixty six'],
            ['hello','there']
            ['once upon a time','in fairyland']
        ]
        expected_output = [
            'a,b',
            '10,sixty six',
            'hello,there',
            'once upon a time,in fairyland'
        ]
        for i in range(len(user_input)):
            with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=user_input[i]):
                output = StringIO()
                with patch('sys.stdout', new=output):
                    two_strings.main()
                    self.assertEqual(output.getvalue().strip(), expected_output[i])
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=['-v'],verbosity=2, exit=False)
```

That will test the python file within the notebook file. I am using jupyterlite. However I am unable to figure out exactly how to setup unit tests for testing multiple lines of input() calls and making sure the output is correct. I know the expected output is correct but knowing how janky using input in jupyter notebooks are in jupyterlite, I want to know if this is possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of testing and looking through documentation it is actually quite simple, as pythons `sys` module allows individuals to directly interact with stdout and stdin:

```py
import sys
from io import StringIO
import unittest

challengeFile = 'challenge.py'
fileRunner = open(challengeFile)
code = fileRunner.read()

class TestName(unittest.TestCase):
    def get_stdout(self, inputs):
        original_stdin = sys.stdin
        original_stdout = sys.stdout
        test_inputs = inputs
        sys.stdin = StringIO('\n'.join(test_inputs))
        sys.stdout = StringIO()
        exec(code)
        script_output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
        sys.stdin = original_stdin
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
        return script_output
    
    def correct(self, test_output, expected_output):
        self.assertEqual(str(test_output).strip(), str(expected_output).strip())
    
    def test_challenge_1(self):
        self.correct(self.get_stdout(["1 1 1 1 1 1"]), "6")

    def test_challenge_2(self):
        self.correct(self.get_stdout(["1 5"]), "6")

    def test_challenge_3(self):
        self.correct(self.get_stdout(["8 11"]), "19")
        
    fileRunner.close()
    
unittest.main(exit=False)
```

This will test the following code (notice how there are no functions!):

```py
s = input().split()
sList = list(map(lambda x: int(x), s))
print(sum(sList))
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to work around usage of `input()` is to abstract it away. Move the `input()` into a function and have it return a tuple of strings. Something like:

```py
def get_inputs():
  return input(), input()
```

You can then mock out the function and have it return hard-coded (or test-generated) strings that your test then uses for validation.

In general, you should not have a unit test rely on `input()` in any way. You want to get rid of that stuff.

If, however, you absolutely *must* test the script as-is even with `input()`, then you'll have to automate passing in input to the script. Which means you can't `import` the script and your alternatives are all bad. In general, what I'm saying can be done here would typically cause me to pull a developer aside and teach them how to properly code. This is not a good idea. Do your best to not do what I'm about to write down.

You have kinda-sorta two choices here: `exec` and `subprocess`.

For `exec`, you are basically running python code as a string in the current scope. So, you can do your own poor-man's mock of `input`, direct local dictionary modifications to something you can monitor, and get things working like that.

```py
def test_something(self):
  # Mock out `input()`
  new_input = lambda: 'some string'

  # Create a locals dictionary you can monitor
  new_locals = {'input': new_input}

  # Execute the code you want to test
  exec(open('two_strings.py').read(), globals(), new_locals)

  # Check the created local variable for the value you want
  self.assertEqual(new_locals['combined'], 'some string,some string')
```

For `subprocess` the code is a bit complicated so I'll elide it and leave it as an exercise for you to fill in the blanks. But, the general idea would be to run the script in its own subprocess, feed it input, and then monitor the output.

You should prefer to use `subprocess` if you don't actually store the result you want to test in a variable you can access from the test. For example, if your print wasn't `print(combined)` but was instead `print(str1 + "," + str2)`.

That being said, running a test like this is a bit crazy.

Comment: I agree with all your points here honestly, its just I need to do it with the script as is, after trying exec, jupyterlite is just throwing a bunch of errors at me but I am pretty sure its unrelated to the code, I assure you this is just because of the constraints I have.

Comment: Apologies if this doesn't work. I didn't have a jupyter environment handy to test this with.